# Show a Jenkins pipeline stage as failed without failing the whole job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

Here's the code I'm playing with

```
node {
    stage 'build'
    echo 'build'

    stage 'tests'
    echo 'tests'

    stage 'end-to-end-tests'
    def e2e = build job:'end-to-end-tests', propagate: false
    result = e2e.result
    if (result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
        stage 'deploy'
        build 'deploy'
    } else {
        ?????? I want to just fail this stage
    }
}
```

Is there any way for me to mark the 'end-to-end-tests' stage as failed without failing the whole job? Propagate false just always marks the stage as true, which is not what I want, but Propagate true marks the job as failed which I also don't want.

Answer (score 71):

This is now possible, even with declarative pipelines:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
        stage('2') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh "exit 1"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('3') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, all stages will execute, the pipeline will be successful, but stage 2 will show as failed:

[image: Pipeline Example]

As you might have guessed, you can freely choose the `buildResult` and `stageResult`, in case you want it to be unstable or anything else. You can even fail the build and continue the execution of the pipeline.

Just make sure your Jenkins is up to date, since this is a fairly new feature.

Comment: I'm getting `Invalid parameter "buildResult", did you mean "null"?` and `Invalid parameter "stageResult", did you mean "null"?`

Comment: @JShorthouse Pipeline: Basic Steps needs to be 2.18 or newer. What version are you on?

Comment: I've found another way that works now but this was probably the problem - I assumed "fairly new" would mean it would work on my couple of months old Jenkins install but from that version's release date I take it you meant within the last week.

Comment: Unfortunately, this marks my failed stage and the pipeline as succeeded.

Comment: Is this magic `sh 'exit 0'` also working on windows installations?

Comment: How do you do this in a scripted pipeline?

Comment: Instead of `sh "exit 1"`, I prefer the more OS independent [error step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#error-error-signal).

Answer (score 27):

Stage takes a block now, so wrap the stage in try-catch. Try-catch inside the stage makes it succeed.

The new feature mentioned earlier will be more powerful. In the meantime:

```
try {
   stage('end-to-end-tests') {
     node {      
       def e2e = build job:'end-to-end-tests', propagate: false
       result = e2e.result
       if (result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
       } else {
          sh "exit 1" // this fails the stage
       }
     }
   }
} catch (e) {
   result = "FAIL" // make sure other exceptions are recorded as failure too
}

stage('deploy') {
   if (result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
      build 'deploy'
   } else {
      echo "Cannot deploy without successful build" // it is important to have a deploy stage even here for the current visualization
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get the following error on «try»: «WorkflowScript: Expected a stage».

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like [JENKINS-26522](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26522). Currently the best you can do is set an overall result:

```
if (result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
    stage 'deploy'
    build 'deploy'
} else {
    currentBuild.result = e2e.result
    // but continue
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do vice versa. To mark unsuccessful Stage with red color, but the status of build (that ball) with blue color?

Comment: Hi @Sviatlana were you able to accompolish this? i.e to mark unsuccessful stage with red color?

Comment: @user3768904 no, I couldn't. We got reed of that.

Comment: @Sviatlana trying the same... Although the build is success, I'd like to mark the stage as failure with red color

Answer (score 14):

I recently tried to use vaza's answer 
[Show a Jenkins pipeline stage as failed without failing the whole job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852310/show-a-jenkins-pipeline-stage-as-failed-without-failing-the-whole-job/42147678#42147678) as template for writing a function that excutes a job in an own stage named like the job name. Surprisingly it worked, but maybe some groovy experts have a look at it :)

Here is how it looks like if one of the jobs is aborted:
[image]

```
def BuildJob(projectName) {
    try {
       stage(projectName) {
         node {      
           def e2e = build job:projectName, propagate: false
           result = e2e.result
           if (result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
           } else {
              error 'FAIL' //sh "exit 1" // this fails the stage
           }
         }
       }
    } catch (e) {
        currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'
        result = "FAIL" // make sure other exceptions are recorded as failure too
    }
}

node {
    BuildJob('job1')
    BuildJob('job2')
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to show a successful build with a failed stage when a downstream job fails ***AND*** support a user being able to cancel a build (including all subsequent stages), I had to use a combination of various solutions, specifically *when*, *try/catch*, *throw* and *catchError()*.

```
env.GLOBAL_BUILD_ABORTED = false        // Set if the user aborts the build

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('First Stage') {
            when { expression { env.GLOBAL_BUILD_ABORTED.toBoolean() == false } }

            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    myLocalBuildMethod('Stage #1, build #1')
                    myLocalBuildMethod('Stage #1, build #2')
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Second Stage') {
            when { expression { env.GLOBAL_BUILD_ABORTED.toBoolean() == false } }

            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    myLocalBuildMethod('Stage #2, build #1')
                    myLocalBuildMethod('Stage #2, build #2')
                    myLocalBuildMethod('Stage #2, build #3')
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def myLocalBuildMethod(myString) {
    /* Dummy method to show User Aborts vs Build Failures */

    echo "My Local Build Method: " + myString

    try {
        build (
            job: "Dummy_Downstream_Job"
        )

    } catch (e) {
        /* Build Aborted by user - Stop All Test Executions */
        if (e.getMessage().contains("was cancelled") || e.getMessage().contains("ABORTED")) {

            env.GLOBAL_BUILD_ABORTED = true
        }
        /* Throw the execiption to be caught by catchError() to mark the stage failed. */
        throw (e)
    }

    // Do other stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following code in your else statement:

```
catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
  error "some err msg"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add a explicit fail task, such as 'sh "not exist command"' in the stage.

```
if (result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
   stage 'deploy'
   build 'deploy'
} else {
   try {
       sh "not exist command"
   }catch(e) {
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Solution steps

- You must emit an error in a stage to mark it as an error
- Outside the scope of the `stage`, handle the exception and choose the build status
- This makes the effect desired by a couple of users here, including myself, @user3768904, @Sviatlana

## Success with failed Step Example

```
node("node-name") {
  try {
    stage("Process") {
      error("This will fail")
    }
  } catch(Exception error) {
    currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
    return
  }
  stage("Skipped") {
     // This stage will never run
  }
}
```

[image]

## Aborted with failure Step Example

```
node("node-name") {
  try {
    stage("Process") {
      error("This will fail")
    }
  } catch(Exception error) {
    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
    return
  }
  stage("Skipped") {
     // This stage will never run
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tested this approach today in a DSL pipeline and it did not work to mark the whole step as a failure, even though there's a failure step within it... Jenkins 2.164.2

Answer (score 0):

This could be a general pattern showing how to customize the stage result with nice messages using the built-in functions and propagate the sub-job's result to the stage result. That the overall build is marked unstable if a sub-job is not successful is just a implementation choice for this example.

```
def run_sub_job() {
    def jobBuild = build(job: 'foo', wait: true, propagate: false)
    def result = jobBuild.getResult()
    def msg = 'sub-job: ' + result
    if ('SUCCESS' == result) {
        println(msg)
    } else if ('UNSTABLE' == result) {
        unstable(msg) // will also set buildResult to UNSTABLE
    } else { // anything else (FAILURE, ABORTED ...) is considered an error
        catchError(
            buildResult: 'UNSTABLE',
            stageResult: result // propagate sub-job result
        ) {
            error(msg)
        }
    }
}
```