# Continue Jenkins pipeline past failed stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a series of stages that perform quick checks.  I want to perform them all, even if there are failures.  For example:

```
stage('one') {
    node {
        sh 'exit 0'
    }
}
stage('two') {
    node {
        sh 'exit 1'   // failure
    }
}
stage('three') {
    node {
        sh 'exit 0'
    }
}
```

Stage `two` fails, so by default stage `three` is not executed.

Ordinarily this would be a job for `parallel`, but I want to display them in the stage view.  In the mock up below:

- Build #4 shows what normally happens.  Job `two` fails so `three` does not run.
- I Photoshopped Build #6 to show what I would like to see.  Job `two` fails and is displayed as such, but `three` still runs.  The real Jenkins would probably display the entire Build #6 tinged slightly red, which is of course fine.

[image: Mock up of desired Stage View result]

Comment: Use try/catch around stage 2

Comment: or built-in `catchError` which also will mark the build red in case of exception.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent comments @EngineerDollery and @izzekil.  I can indeed use try/catch to prevent stage `two` from stopping the pipeline, but now stage `two` is marked as successful--it is green even though it actually failed.

Comment: The closest I could get is to catch the failure, save the failed stage, then after the last stage finishes, set the failed stages as "FAILURE".  However, this requires something like `currentStage` as requested in  [JENKINS-36087](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36087) (superseded by [JENKINS-26522](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26522)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a Jenkins pipeline stage as failed without failing the whole job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852310/show-a-jenkins-pipeline-stage-as-failed-without-failing-the-whole-job)

Comment: @JohnMcGehee...I was also having same issue and solved it using try catch. But i also want to show Red color for my failed stages and green for success one but it is not working. have you found out any solution?

Comment: For completion if someone is looking for the "unstable" state: you can set `currentBuild.result='UNSTABLE'` to make the build "yellow". And you can call `unstable(message: "foobar")` to set one single stage unstable.

Comment: For more completion: If you not only want your job to show the failure but also want your stage to be marked as "FAILURE" just use `catchError(stageResult: 'FAILURE') { ... }`

Comment: My simple suggestion, make use of shell script : $ cmd1 || cmd2: This will run cmd1, and in case of failure it will run cmd2. In your case cmd2 is simple "echo "cmd1 failed, proceeding" Thats all.

Answer (score 129):

This is now possible. Below is an example of a declarative pipeline, but `catchError` works for scripted pipelines as well.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
        stage('2') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh "exit 1"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('3') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, all stages will execute, the pipeline will be successful, but stage 2 will show as failed:

[image: Pipeline Example]

As you might have guessed, you can freely choose the `buildResult` and `stageResult`, in case you want it to be unstable or anything else. You can even fail the build and continue the execution of the pipeline.

Just make sure your Jenkins is up to date, since this is a fairly new feature.

**EDIT:** You need ["Pipeline: Basic Steps" 2.16 (May 14, 2019)](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-basic-steps)

Comment: I guess we could base ourselves by the date the answer has been given, but would you mind, for all clarity, add the date when this has been introduced please and maybe the version ?

Comment: Can catchError has finally block?

Comment: @Turcia, a stage can have a “finally” block, `post { always {}}` independently of `catchError`.

Comment: Doesn't this end up making the overall job look successful though?  If the goal was to just continue running stages after a stage had test failures, the whole job would end up being a false positive and look like it passed even though there were failures in a stage, wouldn't it?

Comment: What about when you have multiple commands in a step, and one of them fails, can you continue executing others?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same concern. I was able to resolve it doing this.

Second stage will show in red and be marked as failed while the rest of the stages will keep running.
You can set a flag and at the end of the stages check the flag and inform the status of the whole build.

```
node {

    def build_ok = true

    stage('one') {
        sh 'exit 0'
    }

    try{
        stage('two') {
            sh 'exit 1'   // failure
        }
    } catch(e) {
        build_ok = false
        echo e.toString()  
    }

    stage('three') {
        sh 'exit 0'
    }

    ....

    if(build_ok) {
        currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
    } else {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
    }
}
```

Comment: You might to give more detail how this solves OP's question.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: In this script what causes `stage('two)` to be marked failed?

Comment: @handras
`sh 'exit 1'` causes that,
this is just an example to see what happen in each case

Comment: @handras note that the try catch is outside of `stage('two')` and the stage will still fail

Comment: The OP is using a declarative pipeline.  This answer is scripted pipeline.  Not sure it provides what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 12):

It depends whether you are using [declarative pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax) or [scripted pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#scripted-pipeline-fundamentals).

**declarative pipeline syntax**:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('one') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
        stage('two') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 1'   // failure
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            sh 'exit 0'
        }
    }
}
```

[Post-condition blocks](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post-conditions) contain [steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-steps) the same as the [steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#steps) section.

**scripted pipeline syntax**:

```
node {

    def build_ok = true

    stage('one') {
        sh 'exit 0'
    }

    try{
        stage('two') {
            sh 'exit 1'   // failure
        }
    } catch(e) {
        build_ok = false
        echo e.toString()  
    }

    stage('three') {
        sh 'exit 0'
    }

    if(build_ok) {
        currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"
    } else {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
    }
}
```

Comment: The declarative answer won't accomplish what the OP was looking for.  If there were a stage three, the 'exit 1' in stage two would prevent stage three from executing.

Comment: @drhender, the declarative syntax does accomplish it. The stage 3 is moved in post-build actions as an always action and that runs even if the build failed. What is correct solution depends on what is needed—catch lets the build continue after failure in specific stage while post-build action is done even if any stage failed.

Comment: @JanHudec, IF there were changes to the declarative answer presented above, it could be made to work.  However, what I said is correct.  As presented above, the declarative answer doesn't address the OP's need.

Comment: where does this currentBuild come from? is this a local variable or something exposed by jenkins? thanks

Answer (score 6):

**Solution:** In order to always continue failed steps in your jenkins pipeline:

**Option 1.** wrap you function in try/catch or in bash script `<someOpertation> || true`

try/catch:

```
script {
  try {
      sh 'do your stuff'
  } catch (Exception e) {
      sh 'Handle the exception!'
  }
}
```

bash always true:

```
script {
  sh 'cp ~/someFile.txt ~/dev || true'
}
```

**Option 2.** run your jenkins pipeline in parallel and set `failFast false` configuration property in your step.

```
    pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Parallel Stage') {
            when {
                branch 'master'
            }
            failFast false
            parallel {
                stage('Branch A') {
                    agent {
                        label "for-branch-a"
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo "On Branch A"
                    }
                }
                stage('Branch B') {
                    agent {
                        label "for-branch-b"
                    }
                    steps {
                        echo "On Branch B"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work. However all boxes are red if even only one fails, but you can see boxes with error marked, so you will easily distinguish failed jobs.

```
def indexes = ['one', 'two', 'three']

node() {
    for (index in indexes) {
        catchError {
            stage(index) {
                println index
                sh '''echo "123"'''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP is using a declarative pipeline-- this example is a scripted pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved that, using post actions:
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/post/

```
           post {
            always {
                ...
            }
           }
```

Answer (score 2):

My simple suggestion, make use of shell scripts beauty like,
$ cmd1 || cmd2: This will run cmd1, and in case of failure it will run cmd2.
In your case cmd2 is simple "echo "cmd1 failed, proceeding next step"
Thats all.
It works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this example:

```
stage('StageName1')
{
    steps
    {
        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE')
        {
            SomeCodeThatCanBeErrored
        }
    }
}
stage('StageName2')
{
    steps
    {
        ContinueOtherCode
    }
}
```

Comment: This idea was already mentioned in [the most rated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56976943/13988450) answer.