# Jenkins Fail at stage based on pipeline log

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to fail this stage if cntKO > 0 but I can only fail the build. Is there any option to just fail the stage?

stages {

```
     stage('Run the Create users based on Env. defined') {
        options { 
            timestamps () 
            timeout(time: 6, unit: 'HOURS')
        }
        steps {
            
           bat 'python batch\\CloudValidation\\Cloudusercreation-csvfile.py %release%'
           bat "batch\\CloudValidation\\usercreationoncloudnew.bat %ws% %release% %username% %pwd% %tenant% %POD%"
           script{
            def pipeline_log1 = currentBuild.rawBuild.getLog(10000);
            def result1 = pipeline_log1.find { it.contains('Total Number of KO Users') }
            if (result1) {
                   User_KO = result1.split("Total Number of KO Users:")
                   cntko = User_KO[1].toInteger()
                   if (cntko > 0)
                    {
                      echo ('Build failed due to' + result1)
                      **currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'**
                    }
                }
          
           }
        }
    }
    
   
     stage('xyz) {
        options { 
            timestamps () 
            timeout(time: 6, unit: 'HOURS')
        }
        steps {
            
            bat "batch\\CloudValidation\\CreatePvtCollabSpace.bat 
      
        }
    }
```

can you please let me know how to address the need?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continue Jenkins pipeline past failed stage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40600621/continue-jenkins-pipeline-past-failed-stage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are already able to fail the build, then just catch the error and only fail the stage without failing the whole build. To do this, wrap your `steps` in `catchError`:

```
steps {
   catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
      ....
   }  
}
```

Comment: This will work if there is an error in the pipeline stage but I want to fail the stage if cntKO > 0. Forcibly mark the failure based on cntKO

Comment: Inside the `if` block, you can add `error "Error message"` and this will forcibly fail the build. However, if you had wrapped the block with the above `catchError`, this failure will be caught.