# Mark a stage in Jenkins Pipeline as eg "UNSTABLE" but proceed with future stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm going to use Jenkins pipeline plugin to test several binaries `A` `B` `C` on  several nodes `1` `2` `3`.
In the end of my test I would like to have every single result of all possible combinations. So my Pipe may not abort when a single stage fails. It should proceed.

```
eg: A1 green, A2 green, A3 red, B1 green, B2 red, ..., C3 green
```

But when the first binary returns with an value unequal zero ("Binary not working on the system") it's stage is marked as FAILURE and any other stages are skipped.

**Is there a possibility in Jenkins Pipeline to mark a stage as "UNSTABLE" but proceed with running the other tests?**

According to [Continue Jenkins job after failed stage while marking stage as failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45223159/continue-jenkins-job-after-failed-stage-while-marking-stage-as-failed) can't mark this step as failed. The solution of this in running tasks in parallel is not working for my setup. So is it possible to safely mark it as *something* else? Is it possible to manipulate the result of a stage?

This question [How to continue past a failing stage in Jenkins declarative pipeline syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45021622/how-to-continue-past-a-failing-stage-in-jenkins-declarative-pipeline-syntax) intents to use a scripted pipeline. I would like to avoid that if it is possible to do it in an other way.

```
pipeline {
    agent {label 'master'}     
     stages {            
        stage('A1') { 
            agent {label 'Node1'} 
            steps {
                sh 'binA'
            }
        }
        stage('A2') {
            agent {label 'Node1'}
            steps {
                sh 'binB' // If this bin fails, all following stages are skipped
            }
        }
// ...        
        stage('C3'){
            agent {label 'Node3'}
            steps {
                sh 'binC'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 24):

**Declarative Pipeline**: Though using `currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'` works in declarative pipelines too, Blue Ocean displays all stages as unstable irrespective of which stage fails.

[image]

To mark only specific stages as unstable, use the step `unstable(message: String)` as described [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Basic+Steps+Plugin) within your stage and install/update the following plugins:

- Pipeline: Basic Steps to 2.16 or newer
- Pipeline: API Plugin to 2.34 or newer
- Pipeline: Groovy to 2.70 or newer
- Pipeline Graph Analysis to 1.10 or newer

**Sample pipeline stage**:

```
stage('Sign Code') {
    steps {
        script {
            try {
                pwd()
                sh "<YOUR SCRIPT HERE>"
            }
            catch (err) {                                        
                unstable(message: "${STAGE_NAME} is unstable")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

> **Note**: This also marks the overall build status as unstable.

Comment: thank you! does the whole thing work for scripted pipeline too? Is there any difference?

Comment: Yes, it works in scripted pipelines too except that you don't need to use the `script{}` block as a wrapper around the try-catch blocks.

Comment: this is marking the entire build as unstable in a scripted pipeline, but does not mark the stage itself as unstable in the UI.

Comment: The documentation seems to indicate that `warnError(message) { code }` does the whole “try-catch + unstable” thing by itself. It may be a bit more concise in many cases. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#warnerror-catch-error-and-set-build-and-stage-result-to-unstable

Answer (score 22):

There is now a more elegant solution, that not only allows you to set a stage and the job result to unstable. Using `catchError`, you can set any combination of stage and build result:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
        stage('2') {
            steps {
                catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                    sh "exit 1"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('3') {
            steps {
                sh 'exit 0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, all stages will execute, the pipeline will be successful, but stage 2 will show as failed:

[image: Pipeline Example]

As mentioned above, you can freely choose the `buildResult` and `stageResult`. You can even fail the build and continue the execution of the pipeline.

Just make sure your Jenkins is up to date, since this is a fairly new feature. (Pipeline: Basic Steps needs to be 2.18 or newer)

Comment: uiiiiii this is blue ocean then? So I need to get grid of the traditional view. This thing makes me happy! thx

Comment: @CuttonEye It works just as well with the traditional view. I just prefer the visualisation of blue ocean. Also, there's no reason you can't use both, depending on your mood. :)

Comment: @ErikB How can we execute custom error-handling code (ex. send mail to sys admins) if code inside `catchError` fails?

Comment: @Mark I think you will have to simply add a try catch inside and rethrow the error after you've sent the email. Just keep in mind that try catch needs to be inside a script block if you are using a declarative pipeline.

Comment: @Mark I created a question for this to be able to give you a code example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73236129/how-to-add-error-handling-code-to-catcherror-in-jenkins/73236130#73236130

Answer (score 5):

For scripted pipeline, you can use try .. catch blocks inside the stages and then set `currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'`

in the exception handler.

Comment: Does there exist some kind of Jenkins built-in constant for string literal `'UNSTABLE'`?

Comment: @Mark Don't know, but I recommend to use the `unstable(message:)` function instead.

Comment: To double-check if your [Jenkins instance (and plugins)](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/07/05/jenkins-pipeline-stage-result-visualization-improvements/) can run the `unstable(message:)` function, go to: http://<YOUR_JENKINS_JOB_URL>/pipeline-syntax/gdsl and check if you find `unstable` in gsdl output