# How to mark build as failed if JS tests fail and mark build as UNSTABLE

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline with running unit tests, when one of them fail it mark build as Unstable, but I need to fail this build and make it red.

Here is an example of my pipeline

```
def gitStatus(buildStatus) {
 if (buildStatus == 'SUCCESS') {
updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: 'build', state: 'success')
addGitLabMRComment comment: 'Build Passed'
}
updateGitlabCommitStatus(name: 'build', state: 'failed')
addGitLabMRComment comment: "Something unexpected happened. Inspect Jenkins logs."
emailext subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT', body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT', to: ''
}

try {
node ('Builder_1') {
    stage('Preparing source tree') {
                    }

stage('Install Dependencies') {
        sh '''#!/bin/bash
           npm install --prefer-offline
      '''
        }

try {

 stage ('Run Tests') {
withEnv(["JEST_JUNIT_OUTPUT=./jest-test-results.xml"]) {
 sh 'npm run test -- --ci --testResultsProcessor="jest-junit"'
}
 junit 'jest-test-results.xml'
}   

      } catch(err) {
        step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: './jest-test-results.xml'])
       throw err
      }

 stage('Build') {
        sh '''#!/bin/bash
           npm run build
      '''
        }
}
}catch (e) {
if (currentBuild.result != 'SUCCESS'){
 currentBuild.result == 'FAILURE'
 }
 throw err
 } finally {
    gitStatus(currentBuild.currentResult)
 }
```

Could you please suggest your thoughts, what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `throw err`, if you use `error err` or `sh "exit 1"`. It will mark the build as red. Hope this helps.

[Follow this post for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852310/show-a-jenkins-pipeline-stage-as-failed-without-failing-the-whole-job)