# Jenkins Pipeline - Trigger jobs sequentially inside a loop

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline where I trigger a single job with different parameters. The number of parameters may also change which changes the number of times the job needs to be triggered. This is why I have the `build job` in a for loop. Here's what the code looks like:

```
pipeline{

    stages{
        stage('Setup'){
            steps{
                script {
                    for (int i=0; i<list_one.size(); i++ ) {
                    def index_i = i
                        for (int j=0; j<list_two.size(); j++) {
                            def index_j = j
                            stage ("${list_one[i]} ${list_two[j]}") {
                                sh "echo 'index_i: ${index_i}'"
                                sh "echo 'index_j: ${index_j}'"
                                build job: 'Downstream Job', parameters: [
                                    string(name: 'some_param', value: "${list_one[index_i]}")]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this pipeline, it only runs once for the first iteration of both the loops. However when I remove the `build job` line, the pipeline runs for all the values in the list. I'm perplexed by why this would be and would like some assistance in the matter.

Comment: hmm is the Job triggered for the first time is passing? if not then it will mark the job as failure and abort rest of the iterations.

Comment: I think there should be a parallel statement.

Comment: No I specifically wanted these jobs to run sequentially, not in parallel. Also, to use `parallel` I think you need to create a map of closures first that includes all these `build job` statements, then pass that to the `parallel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can use something like propagate=false.

[Is there a way to use "propagate=false" in a Jenkinsfile with declarative syntax directly for stage/step?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55723060/is-there-a-way-to-use-propagate-false-in-a-jenkinsfile-with-declarative-syntax)