# How to mark whole Jenkins pipeline build as SUCCESS, after a stage fails and the remaining stages don't run?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My first stage runs a shell script. Exit 0 marks it as success and exit 1 marks it as fail. How can I read this result into the pipeline and get the desired behavior:

- Run stage 1
- If stage 1 fails, don't run the remaining stages, but mark the whole pipeline as a success
- If stage 1 succeeds, run the remaining stages
- If any of them fail, mark the pipeline as a fail
- If they all succeed, mark the pipeline as a success

I am doing this in a declarative pipeline, how can I enforce this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this, catch the error and then change the currentBuild result :

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Stage 1') {
            steps {
                script {
                    try {
                        // do something that fails
                        sh "exit 1"
                    } catch (Exception err) {
                        currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Stage 2') {
            steps {
                echo "Stage 2"
            }
        }
        stage('Stage 3') {
            steps {
                echo "Stage 3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to change a specific stage result, have a look to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36852310/show-a-jenkins-pipeline-stage-as-failed-without-failing-the-whole-job) wich explain how to perform it.

Comment: Yeah, this did it. I defined a boolean variable which was initially set to true and in the "catch" statement I set it to false. Then all the stages which needed to be skipped upon failure were marked with a "when {expression { } }" statement. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's fine to choose which stage needs to be skipped.